# Expand / collapse all buttons above accordion

Tags: usability, accordion, collapsible-panels, panel

I have a typical accordion with 7 items that can individually expand or collapse. I want to place a **collapse all** and **expand all** button above the accordion, but it seems kinda misplaced if it is just two buttons next to each other.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Some input here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66877/whats-wrong-with-accordion-controls

Comment: That's only covering the symbols (I use triangles), but not the expand/collapse **all** issue

Comment: My comment didn't say duplicate, did it?

Comment: No, but it doesn't help me with my issue, either ;) But thanks for the reference

Comment: But maybe it helps others to wrap their head around the topic ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with placing them above the accordion. As long as it is clear that the controls belong to the accordion component that should be fine.